# google app engine and lxml3.0

Tags: python, google-app-engine, lxml

I am a newbie on the google app engine and python dev environment as whole. However, I have past experience with c++, php, and objective-c.

I am trying to write simple html scraper that shows the data. I understand that lxml is the best way to parse html. In my dev environment, I have python 2.7 and i can only seem to install lxml3.0.1. However, app engine supports lxml2.3

Hoping that the differences wont be too bad, I installed lxml3.0.1 on my machine. When i call any lxml.html parser functions it tries to invoke from html5lib - which of course is not supported by app engine.

What is the best way to parse html from google app engine lxml?

Comment: why can't you install 2.3 to match GAE?

Comment: doesn't seem to an option for pip on os x 10.8.2

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/2.3

Comment: that link does not provide options for os x 10.8.2

Comment: I figured out that i donot need to use parser functions from lxml.html just need the standard lxml functions.